# primeng p-multiSelect not dropping down in a component

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to use primeng and multiselect.
In my HTML :

```
<p-multiSelect
  (onChange)="getSelectedIndexesList()"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
  [options]="categories"
  class="multiselect-custom"
  defaultLabel="Select a Category"
  optionLabel="CategoryName"
>
    <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems">
        <div *ngFor="let option of selectedCategories" class="itemlist itemlist-value">
          <div>{{option.DocDescription }}</div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!selectedCategories || selectedCategories.length === 0" class="category-placeholder">
           Select categories
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

Nothing really special. I also imported some modules in my component module:

Here is my implementation:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SearchDocumentComponent
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, SearchDocumentRoutingModule, MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule, MultiSelectModule, DropdownModule    
  ]
})
export class SearchDocumentModule {
}
```

I also imported some modules in my app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, SiteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MultiSelectModule,
    FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule,
    SiteModule, DropdownModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MultiSelectModule,
    FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule,
    SiteModule, DropdownModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I obtain the values in my select but i have issues with the "layout". I don't have dropdown effect

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you share the data for `categories` to the question? Thanks.

Comment: I do have the categories expected ... as values: here is the kind of object I receive: [{ "CategoryID": 1, "CategoryName": "Name", "DocDescription": "Some value", "RelationKey" : 12, Indexes: [] },
{ "CategoryID": 2, "CategoryName": "Another", "DocDescription": "Some value", "RelationKey" : 12, Indexes: [] }]

Comment: Haveing more than one ui-library (ie. Angular Material and PrimeNg) is ususally a bad idea and should be avoided if possible - you can find dropdowns in material aswell

Comment: I finally solved the issue by creating a new Angular project and importing prime ng dependencies first and copying my initial code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p-multiSelect appendTo="body"></p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

to open dropdown with full height you have to use `appendTo` property.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="areas" [(ngModel)]="selectedAreas" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select Areas" **appendTo="body"**></p-multiSelect>
```